# Is it possible to take a direct bus from Tbilisi to Istanbul?

Tags: buses, turkey, georgia-country, istanbul, tbilisi

I'd like to go by bus directly from Tbilisi to Istanbul.

My questions are:

1. What companies run on the route (please list as many as you know)?
2. What bus Station in Tbilisi does each Company operate from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a bus/coach direct from Batumi, Georgia to Istanbul, Turkey?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7072/is-there-a-bus-coach-direct-from-batumi-georgia-to-istanbul-turkey)

Comment: Duplicate does not answer where the asker should be catching the bus from in Tbilisi. All the answers talk about the location of the offices in Batumi, which isn't helpful for this question.

Comment: @Karlson and other close voters. Seriously. **Batumi and Tblisi are different cities**. They're at opposite ends of Georgia. Batumi is on the Western edge of the border with Turkey, Tblisi is in Eastern Georgia, and **there are routes into Turkey from Tblisi that *aren't* via Batumi**. That question is therefore ***related*, not a duplicate**. [**We've been over this**](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3482/can-we-be-more-careful-in-marking-duplicates-on-questions-that-are-related-but-a). Why does this [keep happening](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3628)?

Comment: Note that at this distance it's probably cheaper to take a plane.

Comment: The bus is part of the Point of this trip: it's an overland tour I'm making for fun. Switzerland-Germany-Denmark-Sweden-Finland-Russia-Kazakhstan-Azerbaijan-Georgia-Turkey-Bulgaria-Serbia-Hungary-Austria-Switzerland

Comment: A friend of mine living in Tblisi reports that there are connections that go from Tblisi to Istanbul that can easily be found by [Googling 'tblisi istanbul bus'](https://www.google.com/search?q=%28tbilisi+istanbul+bus&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). They **do** go over Batumi because that is the fastest and most obvious route if you want to avoid the mountains. But if it is for a pleasure trip I can understand that 'the fastest' may not be what you want.

Comment: I understand it goes via batumi, I just don't want to Change buses.

Already found *some* companies (by googling "Otobüs Tiflis Istanbul"), but was hoping to get even more info, **particularly regarding the correct bus Station in Tbilisi for each company**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Metro Turizm](http://www.metroturizm.com.tr/) runs two direct buses a day.
[Lüks Karadeniz](https://eticket.ipektr.com/firms_38/) runs one bus a day.
It seems like both leave from the central Ortachala Bus Station.

It's helpful to know Tbilisi (Gerogria) = *Tiflis (Gürcistan)* in Turkish for their search fields.

Comment: I know of Metro Turizm but I never found any info saying it leaves from Ortachala. Thanks for that